# KendoUI treeview children are displayed as undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a treeview in kendoUI in which main nodes are calling into an mvc controller and that controller looks to whether there is an nullable id passed in and then uses a different model.

What I hit the url  :  http://localhost:2949/Report/GetReportGroupAssignments

I see this JSON

```
[
    {"Id":1,"ReportGroupName":"Standard Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":1},
    {"Id":2,"ReportGroupName":"Custom Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":2},
    {"Id":3,"ReportGroupName":"Retail Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":3},
    {"Id":4,"ReportGroupName":"Admin Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":5},
    {"Id":5,"ReportGroupName":"QA Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":4}
]
```

Now my mvc controller looks like this

```
public JsonResult GetReportGroupAssignments(int? id)
{
    var model = new List<ReportGroup>();
    var defModel = new List<ReportDefinition>();

    try
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            model = _reportService.GetReportGroups("en-us").ToList();
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            defModel = _reportService.GetReportDefinitions().Where(e=>e.ReportGroupID ==Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToList();
            return Json(defModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, "Error loading LoadReportList.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Kendo javascript looks like the following:

```
var serviceRoot = "/Report"; // "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service";
homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: serviceRoot + "/GetReportGroupAssignments", //"/LoadReportTree", // "/Employees",
            dataType: "json" 
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id" //"ReportGroupName"
            ,hasChildren: "Id"
        }
    }
});

var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    expanded: true,
    dragAndDrop: true,
    dataSource: homogeneous,
    dataTextField: "ReportGroupName" 

}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Seems that the calls (which I discovered that children records have a "load" method that it called behind the seens,  so basically I pass in the ID in order to get the data from the other model ( table in db)
(Id is mapped with automapper to ReportGroupID )

So when i click to the left of "Standard Rports" I am getting all of these children as undefined,  How do I get these to show up properly?

[image]

**Update: My ReportDefinition class:**

```
public class ReportDefinition {
    public override int Id { get; set; } 
    public string ReportKey { get; set; } 
    public string ReportName { get; set; } 
    public int? ReportNameResID { get; set; } 
    public string ReportDef { get; set; } 
    public int? ReportDefinitionResID { get; set; } 
    public string ReportAssembly { get; set; } 
    public string ReportClass { get; set; } 
    public int ReportGroupID { get; set; } 
    public int AppID { get; set; } 
    public int SortOrder { get; set; } 
    public bool IsSubReport { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: First, you're misugin the option [`hasChildren`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource#configuration-schema.model.hasChildren). It has to be set as a field in your data telling kendo that the node has or don't has children, that means a *boolean* value. Second, you have to set your [`children`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource#configuration-schema.model.children) field for kendo to know where to look after the children collection.

Comment: Yes, I realizing that my data is not correct  - Should I add in a haschildren with booleans to fix this?   But would that fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have no way to test this scenario to tell you. But take a look on this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/remote-data-binding It seems pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the class `ReportDefinition` does not have a property called: `ReportGroupName`. That is why TreeView displays 'undefined'.

Try adding this Property to your ReportDefinition class like:

```
public class ReportDefinition {

    // Other Properties

    // I guess this property is missing
    public string ReportGroupName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I have "ReportDef"   ,     so the model is   public override int Id { get; set; }
        public string ReportKey { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
        public int? ReportNameResID { get; set; }
        public string ReportDef { get; set; }
        public int? ReportDefinitionResID { get; set; }
        public string ReportAssembly { get; set; }
        public string ReportClass { get; set; }
        public int ReportGroupID { get; set; }
        public int AppID { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubReport { get; set; }

Comment: Wait,  you are saying to add ReportGroupName to the ReportDefinition class, right?   You have a property of ReportDefinition ...

Comment: Yes! Currently it is missing in the ReportDefinition class

Comment: So "Report Name" is property (column) that I want to display in the children,  - do I NEED to do that in the mapping in C# or can i just somehow do this in the javascript ?    schema?

Comment: Kendo just looks at the name. Put the same name in both classes: e.g. public string DisplayName { get; set; }

Comment: Is it just me, or is KendoUI a bit of a pain to work with?

Comment: You are using the control wrong from my opinion. have a look how to bind a IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel> pointet out at: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/local-data-binding

Comment: I use kendo since two years and i think it is the best tool on the market compared to others.

Comment: I agree - that Kendo is best commercial  - I typically use open source jquery to do most things and have a better experience.  I think that I just have to constantly use Kendo to get "good" at it.

Comment: Ok,  so I changed the ReportName to ReportGroupName and then in my automapper mappings I changed to have  Property(t => t.ReportGroupName).HasColumnName("ReportName");     Works Now!

Comment: I'm still not using the haschildren properly with the boolean , I wonder if that is going to "bite me"

Comment: We will see :) Glad i could help

Comment: Hey I had another question FYI     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949967/kendoui-undefined-node-issue-when-trying-to-add-to-root-parent-node