# KendoUI undefined Node issue when trying to add to root parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have seen other questions with the same issue ,  the data seems the be the issue most of the time.

I did create a jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/gwvoqns8/

(always keep in mind that http has to be used, and not https  )

that should demonstrate the problem

1. I want to have whatever is typed into the text box to display as another named node of whatever name...
2. The code I'm using seems to enforce me to selected an existing parent node and i do not want that.

Its a bit annoying why it is saying "undefined"

```
$("#addTopLevel").click(function () {
    console.log('in this');
    if (treeview.select().length) {
        console.log('1');
        treeview.append({
            text: $("#appendNodeText").val()
        }, treeview.select());
    } else {
        //alert("please select tree node");
        console.log('2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        {"Id":1,"ReportGroupName":"Standard Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":1},
        {"Id":2,"ReportGroupName":"Custom Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":2},
        {"Id":3,"ReportGroupName":"Retail Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":3},
        {"Id":4,"ReportGroupName":"Admin Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":5},
        {"Id":5,"ReportGroupName":"QA Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":4}
    ]
});


var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: ds,
    dataTextField: "ReportGroupName",
    loadOnDemand: false
}).data("kendoTreeView");

treeview.expand(".k-item");

$("#addTopLevel").click(function(e) {
    var selectedNode = treeview.select();

    // passing a falsy value as the second append() parameter
    // will append the new node to the root group
    if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
        selectedNode = null;
    }

    treeview.append({
        ReportGroupName: $("#appendNodeText").val()
    }, selectedNode);
});
```

Comment: SWEET!   How about if I want to add a node parent without first selecting a node?  I suppose that how if statement ceremony that i found is just simply not needed, right?

Comment: Oh, I also noticed that in my REAL code not in fiddle, i do have the whole children thing,  so with that IF statement, i select a parent node, and then It uses that ReportGroupName to end up ADDING to the CHILDREN level... ughh not what i want

Comment: kendo.all.min.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

Comment: Again , great work,  that works great   thanks again so much

Answer (score 0):

I was noticing that you could just do this

```
treeview.append({
    ReportGroupName: $("#appendNodeText").val()
}, null);
```

However, OP answer would be better as then you will have the ability to add to children nodes if you wanted to, even though so said you didn't want to.

cheers